# How to Change Actuel Library Version to old version in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.3

I have this error :

> Error: Program type already present:
>
> androidx.versionedparcelable.NonParcelField

to fix it i need to change library version to old version

suggest solution if you have ? and thanks